# Hyperledger instantiate chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

When trying to instantiate chaincode in hyperledger with following command:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.gnaledger.org:7051 peer chaincode instantiate -C gna-channel -n gnacc  -v v0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -o orderer.gnaledger.org:7050
```

I get following error:

```
2018-03-27 23:32:13.195 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-03-27 23:32:13.195 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-03-27 23:32:13.203 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-03-27 23:32:13.203 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-03-27 23:32:13.203 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 005 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken read tcp 172.18.0.7:33712->172.18.0.4:7050: read: connection reset by peer.
2018-03-27 23:32:13.209 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0A9A070A6808031A0B08FDA8EBD50510...1A000A000A04657363630A0476736363
2018-03-27 23:32:13.209 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 7EF3FD93154CC3D3809AA89E945DC21ADCD9EBB9E80BF1D516162F137078FF81
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown
2018-03-27 23:32:13.213 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 008 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken unexpected EOF.
2018-03-27 23:32:13.213 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 009 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: failed to write window update: write tcp 172.18.0.7:33714->172.18.0.4:7050: write: broken pipe"; Reconnecting to {orderer.dcmledger.org:7050 <nil>}
2018-03-27 23:32:13.213 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 00a grpc: addrConn.transportMonitor exits due to: grpc: the connection is closing
Usage:
  peer chaincode instantiate [flags]
```

First a broken pipe, then unable to find the MSP?

Answer (score 0):

The key error is

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown
```

I faced a similar problem. I suggest you double check the capitalisation of the MSP you are using throughout your provisioning process, i.e. `Org1MSP` vs `org1MSP`.

More specifically, one detail I would look at is `configtx.yaml`, `- Org1` element, `ID` key. Normally that's either `org1MSP` or `Org1MSP`. Experiment with that and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

if you tls is ture,you must add: 
 --tls true --cafile ./ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/orderer0.org1.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crfchina.com-cert.pem